# Place image inside image

Tags: c#, image, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a grid that contains 3 rows and 3 columns:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I also have an image in the middle:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="" />
```

[image]

Is there a way to automatically place an image that I load from the user inside this picture? For example to place automatically the image in the green area without having to change by input the user's image resolution.

Comment: What is the green area's row and column number?

Comment: The whole board image row=1 and column=1

Comment: Well. Image is placed where currently ? Can you show how you placed user's image inside this picture?

Comment: Assume is a grid with this board for background, so i could add an image as children to the grid to place the user's image inside this board. But i have to change dimensions then so the user's image fit the board. Can i do this automatically in any way?

Comment: Why you don't use `Margin` and `Padding` for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know the exact dimensions of the board because in different screen sizes the board picture has different dimensions. Could i use Padding and Margin?

Comment: You could set the fixed `Width` and `Height` for user's image and also setting `Margin` and `Padding`.

Comment: Do you want something like [**this**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bDOAt.gif)?

Comment: @JaydenGu yes exactly.How did you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture that you posted is 605px*439px. I measured the picture, and get the border length of the board. Look at the following image:

[image]

When we stretch and shrink the picture, the proportion of the picture will not change. We can make the Grid has stationary proportion.

> You use proportional sizing, also called star sizing, to distribute available space among the rows and columns of a grid by weighted proportions. In XAML, star values are expressed as * (or n* for weighted star sizing). For example, to specify that one column is 5 times wider than the second column in a 2-column layout, use "5" and "" for the Width properties in the ColumnDefinition elements.

For more info, see [Layout properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml#layout-properties)

For example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/blackground.jpg" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="43*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="518*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="44*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="46*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="332*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="61*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Name="MyImage" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```